# Python Multithreading CSV Read Write Sort

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, csv

I have a use case to read from a csv file (inputs.csv) and call an API endpoint for each row of the csv. And write the output into a different csv (outputs.csv) and sort the output csv by a particular column. I am able to achieve all that by the below code. Need to find out if I can do it more efficiently in a multi-threaded way.

```
def main():
start = time.time()
print "read from csv file "
input_file = 'inputs.csv'
output_file = 'outputs.csv'
read_write_csv(input_file, output_file)
print("after output-->",time.time() - start)
sort_csv(output_file)
print("after sort -->",time.time() - start)

def read_write_csv(input_file, output_file):
    with open(input_file, 'r') as csv_file:
        reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        # Reading row by row
        count = 0
        for row in reader:
            # Opening csv result file in append mode
            with open(output_file, "a+") as csv_save:
                writer = csv.writer(csv_save)
                print "mac address ", row[0]
                writer.writerow([row[0], callExternalAPI(row[0])]),(row,))
                print "{0} devices processed so far".format(count+1)
                csv_save.close()

def sort_csv(output_file):
    with open('sorted.csv', 'w') as csv_final:
        r = csv.reader(open(output_file), delimiter=",")
        writer_final = csv.writer(csv_final)
        sortedResponse = sorted(r, key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
        for row in sortedResponse:
            writer_final.writerow(row)
main()
```

As you can see, I am a python newbie here so any suggestion to improve the code is most welcome.

Comment: You can check out the `openpyxl` library to read and write to.csv, .xls or .xlsx files.

Comment: if it comes to performance - your `t.map` and `callExternalAPI` are of interest and their implementation makes an influence

Comment: A parallel sort is non-trivial. Create a [mcve] with nothing to do with csv or calling apis, just with a sequence that needs sorting in parallel.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest sorry t.map was me trying to play around with threading. removed that to avoid confusion. I would like to focus on the read\write\sort of csv's in a performant manner.

Comment: @PeterWood let me try that with a simple array